# Should I delete or answer the question with "solved by restarting"?

Tags: discussion

I have this question [504 Gateway Timeout even when Timeout is set to 600](https://serverfault.com/questions/891201/504-gateway-timeout-even-when-timeout-is-set-to-600) that I can't figure out why it's not working for the whole evening and this morning, It's working just by restarting the server (`shutdown -r now`). Now, should I delete the question or just answer (or comment) it with "solved by restarting the whole server"

Comment: I would say delete it - it's not really a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting is not a solution - it's just getting the symptoms out of the way, without resolving the actual underlying issue. If you're not going to go any further with figuring out the actual problem, I would recommend deleting the question instead.

Comment: If the problem is not actually solved, then theoretically it will come back. So the question still needs an answer. So it seems to me a good course is to edit the question with "restarting has caused the problem to go away, at least for now" and leave it for a more permanent answer.

Comment: so, let the question open until the time it occurred again and I updated it with more findings?

Comment: @ariefbayu It was my idea, and Todd explained the point better, but the community seem to not think like me

Comment: @yagmoth555 yeah, no problem. I guess I'll just let it open and if the community think it should be deleted, I'll let them delete it.

Answer (score -1):

I would post it, if you got that problem  others might too, even if a simple restart resolved the issue.

Comment: thanks, posted the "solved by restarting"

Comment: Surely the goal here should be to have answers that solve the root cause so that people don't have to restart their production servers to 'fix' problems.

Comment: @user449299 its a solution until a real solution is found.

Comment: No, it's a *band-aid* until a real solution is found. A lousy one at that.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It was my point, but the question is well wrote and can deserve a better answer later on is my idea, as we agree that if a reboot resolve the issue, the trouble will most probably come back

Comment: @yagmoth555 it would be good to note that directly in your answer.